# After Upgrading kendo 2020.1.114 to 2022.1.119 the checkbox for is not working How to fix it

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]**It is my textbox**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">
                <span><b>@ResourceManagerClass.GetResource("CCTV Available", ProjectSession.Employee.LanguageId)</b></span>&nbsp;
                    @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsCCTVAvailable).Checked(true).Enable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", @onclick = "ManageCCTVCameraInputBox(event)" })
            </label>
            <br />
            <label class="form-label">
                    @ResourceManagerClass.GetResource("CCTV Detail", ProjectSession.Employee.LanguageId)
            </label>
            <br />
                   @(Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CCTVDetail, 3, 5, new { @class = "form-control textAreaWith" }))
        </div>
</div>
```

**It is jquery**

```
function ManageCCTVCameraInputBox(e) {
    debugger
    if (e != undefined) {
        if (e.currentTarget.checked && e.currentTarget.id == "IsCCTVAvailable") {
            $('#CCTVDetail').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#CCTVDetail').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    } else {
        if ('@Model.IsCCTVAvailable' == "True") {
            $('#CCTVDetail').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
        $('#CCTVDetail').prop('disabled', true);
        }

    }
}
```

It is the code before upgrading it is Working fine but after upgrading kendo to 2022.1.119 then onwards checkbox is not working before if we click checkbox the textarea will open now it is totally disabled When I am enabling the checkbox also it is not opening So how I can fix this

Comment: I can see from the debugger statement that you have tried to debug this. Does the function run on clicking the checkbox? What path is it taking through the code? Can you still run this with the previous version of kendo? If so, what path is that taking through the code?

Comment: Whenever I am debugging with previous version of kendo, In jquery The If loop is running and the Id,  is also binding fine and the textarea is also enabling to user to write something. But After upgrading the project it is directly hitting the else part only Why it is not hitting the If part code the code is same but the version is different.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is probably related to this bug https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/6712 that was fixed with the following version. If you decide to update to [v2022.1.301](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-core-ui/release-history/ui-for-asp-net-core-r1-2022-sp1-(version-2022-1-301)) or later keep in mind v2022.1.301 introduces a dedicated CheckBox component and corresponding jQuery widget, while prior to that the generated `input type="checkbox" />` was receiving only additional styling.

Comment: Yaa,It is working totally fine I have changed to Input type = "Checkbox" but the binding is not changing before upgrading the input type will bind along with the checkbox only but after upgrading it is binding in second line.                                                                                                                       And One more thing my project is small so I will easily edit all the checkboxes if anyone using big project by using kendo......For example in  there project they have 150 checkboxes so he want to change the binding for 150 checkboxes